# Expressions passed down to repository method are not properly compiled

Tags: c#, lambda, linq-expressions, sqlite-net

I have the following call in my ViewModel.

```
Order order= await DataService.Orders.GetAsync(p => p.Id == Guid.Parse("07fafcd9-10db-e511-848d-005056b94716"));
```

The Orders repository has the following method.

```
public async Task<T> GetAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    return await Db.FindAsync<T>(predicate).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

`Db` property is of type `SQLiteAsyncConnection`. The predicate I provided above will translate to the below representation.

```
{p => (p.Id == Parse("07fafcd9-10db-e511-848d-005056b94716"))}
```

The above predicate will throw an exception with the following message

> no such function: parse

So I'm passing the `Guid.Parse` function down which doesn't exist, similar exception it will be thrown if I have the following predicate.

```
Order order= await DataService.Orders.GetAsync(p => p.Id == anotherInstanceObject.Id);
```

The solution is to replace my code with passing the actual value.

```
Guid guid = Guid.Parse("07fafcd9-10db-e511-848d-005056b94716");
Order order= await DataService.Orders.GetAsync(p => p.Id == guid);
```

But the above is so counter intuitive and will introduce a lot of problems when developers will start using the `DataService` class.

I'm using [SQLite.Net-PCL](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL) for my data access.

What am I missing to make the predicate correctly compile down to my repository method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq providers differ in what patterns they support. Yours does not recognize `Guid.Parse`. Is this EF? EF is known to not recognize a lot of the basic .NET Framework functionality that actually could be translated to SQL or evaluated locally.

> what am I missing

Nothing. There is no way to make EF support this besides patching EF or writing your own proxy LINQ provider which is a week worth of work.

You need to live with this. Your would have the same problem without a repository. You just can't write such Linq queries with EF.

Comment: I'm using https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL for my data access locally. I was hoping I don't have to live with it, any links where can I start researching how to fix this writing my own proxy LINQ provider?

Comment: Google for "LINQ provider"... You'll likely not settle on that approach. It is rocket science. I know because I wrote a sophisticated one that does a lot of things. Why are you using this rather exotic Linq provider? I'd try the mainstream EF first. Using such niche frameworks for core infrastructure that is hard to replace is a questionable strategy.

Comment: I can't use EF, need to support a cross platform solution and sqlite-net-pcl is the way to go.

Comment: Alright. Actually, you might find the implementation of "linq toolkit AsExpandable" interesting. Using the exact same way you could implement a simplistic provider that locally evaluates Guid.Parse calls.

Comment: Unfortunately LinqKit has a dependency in EntityFramework 6.1.3, I can't use it in PCL. https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqKit/.

Comment: Copy out the relevant files. You will need to modify the code anyway. It does not do what you need. It's just a sample for how to proxy a query in a simple way.